# Why does the definite article appear before the mass noun 'phloem' in this passage?

Tags: definite-article

> The phloem is often regarded as a relatively straightforward transport
> system composed of loading (collection), long-distance (transport),
> and unloading (release) zones.

Not sure why there is 'the' before 'phloem' as phloem is a mass noun and I have seen this word used in many other articles without a 'the'.  I believe that this sentence is describing generic phloem, not a specific one, so I don't understand why the article is used.

Comment: Why do you think that mass nouns cannot have "the" before them?

Comment: As this is for generic use, I don't understand why it has 'the'. Also, in many articles, this word 'phloem' appears without 'the'. So, please help here.

Comment: For example: "Lignification is a key feature of the differentiation of vessels and fibers in xylem and phloem."

Comment: For what it's worth, the Wikipedia article on phloem includes "the phloem" eight times. There's no rule against it.

Comment: @gotube Thanks. Does it mean that it is optional? Still not sure why the author, who is a native speaker, bothered to use 'the' every time in the article.

Comment: When you use "the" it implies "*the phloem **of a plant***". Without "the", it means phloem in general. There's almost no difference, so it only tells you whether the writer was thinking about the general concept of phloem, or was picturing a particular plant.

Comment: @gotube: We refer to article-less ***liver*** when we're thinking of turning it into pate, or cooking liver and onions. But if I refer to ***the heart*** I'm not necessarily thinking any particular person's heart - I might not even be thinking about human hearts (or even *mammal* hearts; fish have hearts! :) The difference is substance or "organ", not substance in general or that substance in the body of some context-specific "organism".

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think ***phloem, xylem*** are usually better treated as mass nouns, which *don't* use the definite article. But the cited usage is at least "acceptable" either way. I'm more familiar with ***skin*** than ***phloem***, so these are my examples...

> 1: [***The skin is***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20skin%20is%20a%20complex%20organ%22) *a complex organ system comprising the epidermis, the dermis, and the subcutaneous tissues*.

> 2: [***Skin is***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22skin%20is%20a%20complex%20organ%22%20-%22the%20skin%20is%20a%20complex%22&tbm=bks&ei=WNeDZPLxKcOlgAb9m7XgDw&ved=0ahUKEwjy_bPly7f_AhXDEsAKHf1NDfwQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22skin%20is%20a%20complex%20organ%22%20-%22the%20skin%20is%20a%20complex%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQkAlYi3lgw4ABaABwAHgAgAHsAYgBvhiSAQYyMC42LjSYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) *a complex organ whose main function is to protect the body from environmental hazards.*

There are dozens more examples in each of those links. It doesn't really make any difference whether the article is present or not with ***phloem, skin***.

But note that we always include the article with ***the ear, the eye.*** And whereas ***the heart, the liver*** are also bodily organs, ***heart, liver*** with no article are "mass noun" *foodstuffs*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But as the author of this article is a native speaker, I guess he must have a reason to add 'the' before 'phloem' so many times in the paper (also in the Wiki article on phloem).

Comment: I'm not a biologist, but it seems quite reasonable to me that a person working in this area might think of "the phloem" as a "system" within the plant, rather that just a "substance". Certainly that's what we all do with "skin" (both a biological system and a substance).

Comment: ...in any case, your cited example says "the phloem" is *a relatively straightforward transport **system***. If it's a "system" or an "organ", it can take an article.